# Dynamically second field select value based on first select value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, formik

I am using React and Formik. I have initial values set.

```
initialValues={{
                    Department: "",
                    Category: "",
}}
```

Department and Category are material ui menus dependent on each other. If user selects a value from Department then Related categories will get updated.

New we get new initial values from api like this

```
initialValues={{
                    Department: "IT",
                    Category: "Forgot Password",
}}
```

Values are being set for both menus. but Category is not being filled as its data is being populated on change of Department. How to trigger change so that Categories will get values and i can set the data which i got from api.
Formik code

```
<Formik
    enableReinitialize={true}
    initialValues={{
        Department: "IT",
        Category: "Forgot Password",

    }}

    innerRef={formRef}
    validateOnChange={true}
    validateOnBlur={false}
    validate={values => { }}
>
    {({ values, touched, errors, handleChange, handleBlur, isValid, setFieldValue }) => (


        <Form noValidate autoComplete="off" >

            <Grid container spacing={3}>
                <Grid item lg={4} xs={12}>
                    <FormControl className={classes.fullWidth} error={Boolean(errors.Department && touched.Department)}>
                        <InputLabel id="Department">Department</InputLabel>
                        <Select
                            name="Department"
                            labelId="Department"
                            id="Department"
                            onChange={(e, value) => {
                                setFieldValue('Department', value === null ? "" : value.props.value);
                                setFieldValue('Category', "");
                                departmentChange(value.props.value);
                            }}

                            fullWidth
                            value={values.Department}
                        >

                            {departmentList && departmentList.map((department, index) => {
                                return (
                                    <MenuItem key={index} value={department.Department}>{department.Department}</MenuItem>
                                )
                            })}

                        </Select>
                        <FormHelperText className={classes.error}>{(errors.Department && touched.Department) && errors.Department}</FormHelperText>

                    </FormControl>

                </Grid>

                <Grid item lg={4} xs={12}>
                    <FormControl className={classes.fullWidth} error={Boolean(errors.Category && touched.Category)}>
                        <InputLabel id="Category">Category</InputLabel>
                        <Select
                            name="Category"
                            labelId="Category"
                            id="Category"
                            onChange={handleChange}
                            fullWidth
                            value={values.Category}
                        >
                            {categoryList && categoryList.map((category, index) => {
                                return (
                                    <MenuItem key={index} value={category.Category}>{category.Category}</MenuItem>
                                )
                            })}
                        </Select>
                        <FormHelperText className={classes.error}>{(errors.Category && touched.Category) && errors.Category}</FormHelperText>
                    </FormControl>

                </Grid>

                <Grid item lg={12} xs={12} align="right">

                    <div className={classes.wrapper}>
                        <Button
                            className={classes.button}
                            type="submit"
                            color="primary"
                            variant="contained"
                            disabled={showButtonLoader}
                        >
                            submit
                    </Button>
                        {showButtonLoader && <CircularProgress size={24} className={classes.buttonProgress} />}
                    </div>

                </Grid>

            </Grid>

        </Form>)}

</Formik>
```

[image]

Comment: post your whole code, mate.

Comment: I have added the code.Let me know if this is sufficient

Comment: What is this -> `departmentChange(value.props.value)`? Where is `value` coming from?

Comment: On change of the department, i m pulling relevant categories from the object. The value is one selected in department dropdown.

Comment: This is probably related to React lifecycle issue, how do you pass the data into Formik when you get new data?